# Android emulate back pressed from a Service

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing a utilitiy application that will automate certain tasks for the user, such as opening an app and then going back to the previous activity.

For this specific functionality, I have a background service that starts a third party activity via `startActivity()`, waits for a few seconds for the activity to loads completely and then bring the user back by emulating a Back button press.

I am stuch at the Back button press emulation. I don't want to just start the Launcher activity to bring the user to the home screen. I want him to go back to what he last used.

Answer (score 3):

At first I thought it would be impossible without root access, but I believe this may work:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " + KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
} catch (IOException e) {/*...*/}
```

UPDATE:
I put it in AsyncTask for testing and it doesn't seem to work when outside own activities :(  [This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.app58us.backkey&hl=en) works as accessibility service, so maybe that is the only way..

Comment: That's certainly interesting, mutual plus one?

Comment: Thank you, but I still need 4 rep points to upvote :/  Will come back here when I get them :)

Answer (score 1):

With activities of other apps, forcing them to call `finish()`, is not possible. You can send a broadcast from the service; then any activity that is open can listen to the broadcast and then decide to take appropriate action.

The problem with `Ineptus` answer is that keyboard may have different mappings of an input-event-value to its functionality.

See: http://thecodeartist.blogspot.com/2011/03/simulating-keyevents-on-android-device.html

Not sure if this could help:

```
this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
```